# Simulate confidence intervals for the absolute difference between two hazard ratios

Tags: confidence-interval, cox-model, stratification

I am examining the time to an (recurrent) event in response to different medications between men and women. I am adopting a 'within-individual' design whereby each person's time spent on- and off- the medication are presented as separate or unique rows for that particular person (i.e., counting process approach or Anderson-Gill approach). This allows for each person to be their own controls during the periods they are medicated versus the periods of time they are not. By considering each person as their own stratum, a stratified (extended) cox proportional hazards model could then be used to the attain the hazard ratio (HR) of the outcome in response to the particular drugs and other time-dependent covariates (time-independent covariates e.g., sex, gender, etc would already be controlled for by the nature of this design).

The issue is however that I seek to find the difference between men and women - both fixed/time-independent covariates.

I therefore intend on either using the subset argument within `survival::coxph()` to analyze data restricted to men and women, respectively or by running each model separately in data restricted to men and women, respectively (I feel it'd be the same outcomes). Nevertheless, I would then have a HR (and confidence interval [CI]) for men and women, respectively.

*I ask whether it'd be possible to simulate (e.g., bootstrap, Monte Carlo, etc.) confidence intervals for the difference in the magnitude of the HR between men and women?*

For example. Say, the HR and (95% CI) for drug x is 0.75 (0.60 - 0.80) for men and 0.60 (0.50 - 0.70) for women. The difference in magnitude of the HR would thus be 0.15; however, how would/could I go about attaining the confidence interval for this absolute difference in HRs? Any recommend literature, packages, etc. would be greatly welcomed..

Other counsel/suggestions/comments would be appreciated...